# Enthought Canopy python install of pygtk

Tags: pygtk, enthought, rhel5, canopy

I am using the latest enthought canopy  1.0.1 on Red Hat 5.9
It is installed on top of the stock python 2.4.3

I have some applications written against pygtk and would like to use them with the Enthought version. By the way pygtk works great with the native python 2.4.3.

Canopy doesnt seem to install pygtk via the GUI. And when I use easy_install I get this error:

Error Message :

```
~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/easy_install
[john@localhost site-packages]$ easy_install pygtk
Searching for pygtk
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pygtk/
Reading http://www.pygtk.org/
Reading http://www.pygtk.org
Reading http://www.daa.com.au/~james/software/pygtk/
Reading http://www.daa.com.au/~james/pygtk/
Reading http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/
Best match: pygtk 2.24.0
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/PyGTK/pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2#md5=a1051d5794fd7696d3c1af6422d17a49
Processing pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2
Writing /tmp/easy_install-_GU7D6/pygtk-2.24.0/setup.cfg
Running pygtk-2.24.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-_GU7D6/pygtk-2.24.0/egg-dist-tmp-qria80
error: Setup script exited with ********************************************************************
* Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. *
* To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.    *
****************************************************************
```

When I try "the supported way" using ./configure and make

I get this error:

```
checking for python version... 2.7
checking for python platform... linux2
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.7/site-packages
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.7/site-packages
checking for headers required to compile python extensions... not found
configure: error: could not find Python headers
```

It is finding the correct python , but I cannot determine how to install the enthought headers.
In canopy there was a package Debug Headers 0.1, which will not install because Paste has an error installing.

Thanks for any help,

Just trying to get pygtk working against the enthought python.
Any suggestions?